# imaplib.error: command FETCH illegal in state AUTH

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to download attachments from Gmail, using a combination of pieces of code I found online, and some editing from myself. However, the following code:

```
import email, getpass, imaplib, os, random, time
import oauth2 as oauth
import oauth2.clients.imap as imaplib

MY_EMAIL = 'example@gmail.com'
MY_TOKEN = "token"
MY_SECRET = "secret"

consumer = oauth.Consumer('anonymous', 'anonymous')
token = oauth.Token(MY_TOKEN, MY_SECRET)

url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/b/"+MY_EMAIL+"/imap/"
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

m.authenticate(url, consumer, token)

m.select('INBOX')

items = m.select("UNSEEN"); 
items = items[0].split() 

for emailid in items:
    data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
```

returns this error:

> imaplib.error: command FETCH illegal
>   in state AUTH

Why would Fetch be illegal while I'm authorized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're lacking error checking on your calls to select.  Typically, this is how I'll structure the first parts of a connection to a mailbox:

```
# self.conn is an instance of IMAP4 connected to my server.
status, msgs = self.conn.select('INBOX')

if status != 'OK':
  return # could be break, or continue, depending on surrounding code.

msgs = int(msgs[0])
```

Essentially, the trouble you're encountering is that you've selected a mailbox that doesn't exist, your status message is probably not "OK" as it should be, and the value you're iterating over isn't valid.  Remember, select expects a mailbox name.  It does not search based on a flag (which may be what you're attempting with "UNSEEN").  When you select a non-existent mail box you actually get this as a response:

```
('NO', ['The requested item could not be found.'])
```

In which case, `for email id in items` is not operating properly.  Not what you're after in any way, unfortunately.  What you'd get on a valid mailbox would be like this:

```
('OK', ['337'])
```

Hope that helps.

To address the question in comments, if you want to actually retrieve the unseen messages in the mailbox you'd use this:

```
status, msgs = self.conn.select('INBOX')
# returns ('OK', ['336'])

status, ids = self.conn.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
# returns ('OK', ['324 325 326 336'])

if status == 'OK':
  ids = map(int, ids[0].split())
```

The response is going to be similar to the response from select, but instead of a single integer for the number of messages you'll get a list of ids.

Comment: Hmm I see, thanks. Slightly related: how would I search for unseen emails? m.search("UNSEEN") gives an error as well.

Comment: @JacobK - To get unseen messages you want this (after selecting a mailbox):  `conn.search(None, 'UNSEEN')`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why would Fetch be illegal while I'm authorized?

IMAP has a state concept.

You can only fetch messages if you have **selected** a folder.

Here is a nice picture which shows this:

[image: IMAP States]

Image source: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IMAP4GeneralOperationClientServerCommunicationandS-2.htm